# Select all Cells at once above limit value

Tags: excel, vba

I can Select only the Cells with in region that contain numbers:

`Region.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants , xlNumbers)`

but I don't know how to Select only the cells that are above a number. For example those above 1.0

I have a big Sheet with numbers and I want to cap all numbers above 1, and set them to 1. I would love to do it without having to loop on each cell.

thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any out-of-the-box way to do that.  You're going to have to do *some* looping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say, forget about `SpecialCells`. Just load all cells that need testing into a Variant array. Then loop over that array and do your capping. That is very efficient, contrary to looping over cells in a sheet. Finally, write it back to the sheet.

With 50,000 cells containing random values between 0 and 2, this code ran in 0.2 s on my antique laptop.

The added bonus is that this is quite clear and readable code, and you retain full control over what range will be operated on.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim v As Variant
Set r = Sheet1.UsedRange
' Or customise it:
'Set r = Sheet1.Range("A1:HZ234") ' or whatever.
v = r ' Load cells to a Variant array

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
    For j = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
        If IsNumeric(v(i, j)) And v(i, j) > 1 Then
            v(i, j) = 1 ' Cap value to 1.
        End If
    Next j
Next i

r = v ' Write Variant array back to sheet.
```

Comment: +1 for the variant. *BUT* a variant with `SpecialCells` is better again. Why process all the cells in a 2D range with a nice bread knife when you could use a scalpel to process only the numeric constants (Sure the time goes from tiny to microscopic but efficiency is beautiful :)

Comment: Thanks!. I think I'll use this one. Seems the most readable and short.

Comment: @brettdj: Well, my analogy would be: why do telesurgery using complicated robotic tools, when the patient is in the house next door? Just bring the patient into the clean, sterile operation room and use your knife of choice at point blank, and then send them home. The only "processing" that is done on *all* cells is reading, checking one boolean (`IsNumeric(v(i, j))`), and writing back.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett while I was being tongue in cheek I do think adding `SpecialCells` to the variant array is a small and simple improvement that could potentially make a difference depending how often the code was called. I don't think recommending discarding an efficient process the OP is clearly comfortable with is good pratice.

Answer (score 4):

This method below avoids the cell by cell loop -  while it is significantly longer than your range loop code I share your preference for avoiding cell by cell range loops where possible

I have updated my code from [A fast method for determining the unlocked cell range](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2769-A-fast-method-for-determing-the-unlocked-cell-range.html) to provide a non cell by cell loop method

1. the code checks that `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants , xlNumbers)`
   exist on the sheet to be updated (error handling should always be
   used with `SpecialCells`
2. if these cells exist, a *working sheet* is created, and a formula is inserted into the range from step 1 to create a deliberate error (the 1/0) if the value on the main sheet is >1
3. `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)` returns a range of cells from the working sheet where the values were greater than 1 (into `rng3`)
4. All areas in `rng3` are set to 1 with `rng3.Value2=1`

   ```
   Sub QuickUpdate()
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Dim rng3 As Range
   Dim lCalc As Long

   Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng1 = ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers)
   On Error GoTo 0
   'exit if there are no contants with numbers
   If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   'disable screenupdating, event code and warning messages.
   'set calculation to manual
   With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = False
       .EnableEvents = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       lCalc = .Calculation
       .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   End With

   ws1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
   Set ws2 = ActiveSheet
   'test for cells constants > 1
   ws2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF('" & ws1.Name & "'!RC>1,1/0,'" & ws1.Name & "'!RC)"
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng2 = ws2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
   On Error GoTo 0

   If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
       Set rng3 = ws1.Range(rng2.Address)
    rng3.Value2 = 1    
              Else
       MsgBox "No constants < 1"
   End If
   ws2.Delete

   'cleanup user interface and settings
   With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = True
       .EnableEvents = True
       .DisplayAlerts = True
       lCalc = .Calculation
   End With

   'inform the user of the unlocked cell range
   If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Cells updated in Sheet " & vbNewLine & ws1.Name & vbNewLine & " are " & vbNewLine & rng3.Address(0, 0)
   Else
       MsgBox "No cells updated in " & ws1.Name
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: On my bb so not well placed to edit but on reflection a simple one off `rng3.Value=1` would suffice for writing a single value. So no need to loop areas

Comment: +1 Dave :) Nice code. I specially like the part SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors). BTW I guess you meant MsgBox "No constants > 1" instead of MsgBox "No constants < 1" ?

Answer (score 2):

What is the harm in looping? I just tested this code on a range of 39900 cells and it ran in 2 Secs.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range, aCell As Range

    Set Rng = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

    For Each aCell In Rng
        If aCell.Value > 1 Then aCell.Value = 1
    Next aCell
End Sub
```

My only concern is the use of SpecialCells as they are unpredictable and hence I rarely use them.

Also have a look at this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=832293

Comment: Sid, did you have 40K numbers in those cells? The limitation of 8192 areas - which in my experienc is rarely breached - has been removed in xl2010

Comment: Yes (39900 to be precise) from B7 to T2106 (Tested in Excel 2003)

Comment: What is the harm in looping over cells? Well, 2 seconds is an order of magnitude worse than the next best solution. What if there are 400,000 values to check next time? What if the OP has to run the code 100 times?

Comment: JFC :) I am aware of the adverse affect of looping. My question was specific to this particular scenario ;)